# Nodejs 8 - How to use Async/Await with mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose

im running nodejs version v8.5.0 using nvm.

I have a simple index function which returns all the users in my mongo db using mongoose.

```
User.find({}, (err, results) => {

            if (err) {
                return res.json(err);
            }

            return res.json(results);
});
```

I'm trying to convert the traditional call back approach to the new async and await.

user.controller.js

```
'use strict';

const User           = require('../models/user.model');

class UserController {

    constructor() {

    }

    async index(req, res) {

        try {
            let result = await User.find({});
            return res(result);

        } catch (e) {
            return res.json(e);
        }

    }

    show(req, res) {

    }

    update(req, res) {

    }

    store(req, res) {

    }

    destroy(req, res) {

    }

}

module.exports = UserController;
```

user.route.js

```
'use strict';

let express    = require('express');
let router     = express.Router();
let controller = require('../controllers/user.controller');
controller     = new controller();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.store);
router.put('/:id', controller.update);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

However when i run this, i get an empty object back.

Comment: Show what is calling `index()`.

Comment: @zero298 updated my question

Comment: _an empty object back_, you mean `{}`?

Comment: @alexmac yes it returns {}, no errors.

Comment: Does `result` get populated in `index()`?

Comment: Yes it does, and the traditional approch works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The empty object is the error (calling res.json(javascript_error) will return an empty object).

Instead of

```
return res(result);
```

use

```
res.send(result)
```